# Typhoon Injection - Crashing when injecting parameters using initializer

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, typhoon

I am following Typhoon Coredata example (https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon-CoreData-RAC-Example) to configure coredata in swift.

But i am getting exception in the following method

```
public dynamic func managedObjectModel() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(NSManagedObjectModel.self){
            (definition) in
            definition.useInitializer("contentsOfURL:"){
                (initializer) in
                 initializer.injectParameterWith(self.modelUrl())
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above function, i am trying to inject modelurl to "contentsOfURL" method of NSManagedObjectModel class. But i am getting following error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Method 'contentsOfURL:' not found on 'NSManagedObjectModel'. Did you include the required ':' characters to signify arguments?'
```

//

```
//NSManagedObjectModel class  
    public convenience init?(contentsOfURL url: NSURL)
```

Comment: using Objective C method "initWithContentsOfURL:" instead of "contentsOfURL:" fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
definition.useInitializer("initWithContentsOfURL:")
```

Comment: It would help if you explain your answer.

Comment: class NSManagedObjectModel has a method                                      - (instancetype)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url (Objecive C)

Comment: please do so in the question itself.